# How to duplicate ies light

Tags: light

I have added an ies light. I want to duplicate the lamp with the ies light. When i select the lamp and the light and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the mesh duplicate but there is no light. And i cant control the duplicate light also. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are mistaking "lamp rig 10" for the actual light itself. This is only a mesh made of edges that acts as a parent to the light, making it easier to select. When you are duplicated the lamp, you only selected the lamp mesh and the lamp rig but not the actual light itself. Try going into wireframe mode and box-select (b) the lamp, which will include the actual light. Duplicating this should not have any problems.
[image]

Comment: It is a good practice to verify and make selections in wireframe mode.

Comment: @LeoNas Typically it's not necessary, except in situations like this where you have many overlapping objects. Then I would recommend always going into wireframe just to make sure you've selected everything you intented to select.